# PHP: change variables_order from EGPCS to GPCS

Tags: php, variables

i am new to PHP. I want to change the variable_order from EGPCS tp GPCS. Please suggest that how can I do this task ?

Answer (score 6):

PHP.ini `variables_order` directive.

Or use [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/function.ini-set.php) function at runtime. **Update** `ini_set` won't work, see [description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: <?php
ini_set('variables_order','GPCS');
echo 'variables_order = ' . ini_get('variables_order') . "\n"; ?>  

It still show EGPCS.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php. Looks like you have to use .htaccess or some other directory-specific mechanism to change it.